# Source Control: Supporting multiple versions of a software

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs

The source control that my .NET WPF project uses is TFS. The customers for the project are all internal to the company. In near future we are going to release one version to only one customer because of a set of special requirements.

So we plan to create another branch in TFS and incorporate these requirements. The problem is that the customer may demand long term support for this version and may only want defect fixes to go into the product and not any new features that we incorporate on the main branch.

Though this is quite manageable currently, my fear is that 1-2 years down the line, we may end up having multiple source code branches which will create a maintainability headache of supporting n number of versions.

Could you please suggest ways to keep this entire situation manageable, or whether our approach of creating multiple branches itself is wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the question is much more about a business then about the technology to use.

Are you sure that this is your only customer that will need that kind of treatment from your company (I imagine it's important customer) ?

- Yes. In this case just make a branch. Setup automated test scripts. On *every* commit you made on the *main branch* that should be present also int *customer branch* make a merge. Run your nightly scripts to check integrity
- No. I would say do not make branch, at this point (at the end how much branches you gonna manage contemporary..) and use configuration option *in the code*. That means clear separation of the features available for one customer, or for another. The features can be available based on some configuration option available in your application's configuration file. If, you want to make the stuff more tricky, as clients are able to manipulate files, can invent License types (keys) whom computed hash aggregates *not shared* features availibility.

Unfortunately the branching is always headache in centralized code versioning systems. In distributed systems it's managed in much better way, but, by the way, completely avoid conflict, especially in long term run, is almost impossible in both cases.

Good luck.

Comment: This configuration options sounds like a good idea. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create the branch for the released version, and on each subsequent release you make from that branch (since you're only making bug fixes), every time you release from that "bug fix branch", don't re-branch, but create a tag so you can reference easily.

Comment: This is the same plan that we have currently. But my fear is that 1-2 years down the line there might be a lot of branches going out from the main branch all having a mix and match of features and bug fixes

Comment: @Jason: And don't forget to merge your release branches' bug fixes into the trunk/main branch before the branches start to diverge too much.

Comment: @ganeshran to achieve this, make sure that your customers get a new release starting from the main branch when they need significant feature work. Then you can forget about their previous branch from then on.

Comment: @ganeshran I think this is your best approach if you are going to support multiple version of a product for bug fix purpose and where features are not carried over to the other version.  The alternatives would be more cumbersome imho, and eventually some of those branches/versions should die off, put enough features and must haves in the next version(s) so there is little to no incentive in staying in the really old versions, like say why use v1 when v5 has so much more, or v1 runs on Win2000 32Bit, but they're now running Win7 64bit  :)

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan I assumed anyone looking into branching (or claims to already be doing branching) already knows that basic step  :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you study the **TFS branching guide by Visual Studio ALM Rangers**. It's quite some reading, but a good one, and you should be able to find a scenario there that suits you - and is advisable when using TFS. You find it here: http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/